# Is this a Jacaranda or a Silk Tree or something else?

Tags: identification, trees, flowering

Back in March, I bought a baby Jacaranda tree from Ebay. Well, they claimed it was a Jacaranda.  Just recently I discovered Silk Trees which look remarkably like the Jacaranda.  Everywhere I read, articles said the best way to tell them apart is by their flowers.  Well either tree won't flower until a few years old. So is there any other way I can distinguish between the two? Is what I purchased a Jacaranda or a Silk Tree...or even something else?  Here's some helpful info which may help identification:

1. I purchased the tree as a tiny little sapling for $10 on Ebay.
2. It was not bare root nor was it grafted. Def grown from seed.
3. The seller was growing them in Florida.
4. I live in Southern Texas.
5. This tree has thrived in my clay soil with only watering once a week.
6. Just came out of a drought too so the tree had no real rain water.
7. The tree grew from about 1 inch tall to over 5 feet in about 6 months!
8. Has one main trunk, though started sprouting a secondary one at ground level

Plethora of pics:
[image: Whole Tree]
[image: Leaf]
[image: Leaf - Some of the leaflets curl]
[image: Closeup of leaflet]
[image: Tip of the tree]
[image: Trunk 1]
[image: Trunk 2e]

Comment: My mother had a silk tree, but hers was more umbrella shaped, these have fronds all the way down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a jacaranda, also not flowering yet, which I know to be a jacaranda because it was also planted from a seed. It seems to be pretty easy to sprout these jacaranda seeds, so I would be inclined to believe your e-Bay seller for that reason alone. But also your tree looks just like my J. tree: trunk-dots, fluffy leaves, branches, fast growing, everything.

But. . . Now that you point out the similarity between silk tree (i.e. Albizia julibrissin or "mimosa tree"?) leaves and those of Jacaranda, boy they *do* look alike, even though not closely related at all. However, here is a "frond" off of my tree[image: jacaranda leaflets]

The little "branchlets" (don't know what they're really called) have a single leaflet sticking out at the very tip, and notice the deep groove down the center of each leaflet. Just like in your photos. My end-leaflet looks a little longer than yours though.

I don't have an Albizia silk tree handy, but checking the [internet](https://tedmanzer.com/2012/07/09/invasive-silk-tree/), it looks like they don't have a leaflet at the very tips of the branchlets. So they do look a tiny bit different from the jacaranda.

[image: silktree leaf]

[Invasive silk tree](https://tedmanzer.com/2012/07/09/invasive-silk-tree/0)

So I think it truly is what it claims to be - Jacaranda.

Comment: I think you are right - the presence of terminal leaflets points to _Jacaranda_ and not _Albizia_. For those that have something similar looking and want an ID, it is worth noting that a number of _Acacia_ species are also very similar in appearance.

Comment: Paradise tree (Simarouba glauca) is another near match: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simarouba_glauca There are quite a few compound leaf trees like this, even Locusts. Sooner or later the flowers will tell the story.